# SQL select latest message of every conversation received AND sent

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

This question  [SQL select only rows with max value on a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column)  doesn't solve my problem although it has been marked as duplicate.

It assumes my columns `from_id` and `to_id` are primary keys, when they don't have such constraint (see code provided bellow). If they were primary keys, I couldn't store my messages in the same table. As a result the SQL query of this answer prints all duplicates multiple times, which is **not** what I want. Please see expected behaviour bellow.

Expected behaviour : I need to select the latest message from all conversations, **regardless of whether** the user is only sender, recipient, or both. Each conversation/thread **should only be displayed once**.

Example : when querying this table, my SQL statement should only output msg3 and msg4, ignoring all the previous messages John and Alice exchanged.

[image]

Here is the closest query I could write. Problem is this query only selects conversations where user received a message. I'm stuck adding conversations where user is only sender (he didn't get any reply) to the selection.

```
SELECT * FROM messages where `to_id` = '1' GROUP BY `from_id` ORDER BY `send_date` ASC
```

Here are `users` and `messages` tables:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    name VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE messages (
    id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    to_id INT(11) NOT NULL,   //recipient id to match to current user id
    from_id INT(11) NOT NULL, //sender id to match to current user id
    send_date DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    content TEXT
);
```

**Question:** How can I do this using a single SQL query ? Or should I change my data structure using three tables instead of one ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would first get the ids.  You can do this using `least()` and `greatest()`:

```
select least(m.to_id, m.from_id) as id1,
       greatest(m.to_id, m.from_id) as id2, max(m.id) as max_id
from messages m
group by id1, id2;
```

You can then get the complete information about the message by `join`ing back:

```
select m.*
from messages m
where m.id in (select max(m.id) as max_id
               from messages m
               group by least(m.to_id, m.from_id), greatest(m.to_id, m.from_id)
              );
```

Note:  In older versions of MySQL, putting the subquery in the `from` clause and using `join` is much more efficient.